# How to avoid init override in Java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am facing a problem like this.

```
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double balance;
    private static int nextID;
    int acctID;

    Account(String n, double bal) {
        init();
        this.name = n;
        this.balance = bal;
        print();
    }

    void init() {
        this.acctID = nextID++;
    }
}

public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    private double interest;

    public SavingsAccount(String n, double bal, double interest) {
        super(n, bal);
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    void init() {
    }
}
```

The class SavingsAccount will use its init() and this is wrong. I know I can do this to solve the problem.

```
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double balance;
    private static int nextID;
    int acctID;

    Account(String n, double bal) {
        init();
        this.name = n;
        this.balance = bal;
        print();
    }
    {
        this.acctID = nextID++;
    }
}
```

I would like to ask if there any other way to solve this problem, for example force other class to use the Account.init() or don't allow others to make their only init()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the `init()` method `final`, then nobody can override it.

```
final void init() {
    this.acctID = nextID++;
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html